# When is this sine function differentiable at all points?

Tags: derivatives

I have a hard time solving these kinds of problems, here is an example. For which values of a and b is the following function differentiable at all points? $$f(x)=\sin(|x^2+ax+b|)$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote my answer, too @kalex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the quadratic isn't positive, namely when $\;\Delta =a^2-4b\le0\;$ . Can you see what's the problem with the absolute value of something that vanishes?

**Added**: suppose the quadratic vanishes at $\;x_0< x_1\;$ , so that $\;x^2+ax+b=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\;$ .

Observe that if $\;h<0\;$ is such that $\;x_0-x_1+h>0\;$ , then $\;f(x_0+h)=\sin|h(x_0+h-x_1)|\;$ , with $\;h(x_0+h-x_1)<0\;$ .

Now, by definition:

$$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{sin(|h(x_0+h-x_1)|)-\overbrace{0}^{=f(x_0)}}{h}=$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\,(x_0+h-x_1)\frac{\sin\left(-h(x_0+h-x_1)\right)}{h(x_0+h-x_1)}=\color{red}-\lim_{h\to 0^-}\,(x_0+h-x_1)\frac{\sin\left(h(x_0+h-x_1)\right)}{h(x_0+h-x_1)}=$$

$$=x_1-x_0$$

whereas

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\sin(|h(x_0+h-x_1)|)-\overbrace{0}^{=f(x_0)}}{h}=$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\,(x_0+h-x_1)\frac{\sin\left(h(x_0+h-x_1)\right)}{h(x_0+h-x_1)}=x_0-x_1$$

Thus, both one sided limits aren't equal so the limit definint the derivative at $\;x_0\;$ doesn't exist and thus $\;f'(x_0)\;$ doesn't exist.

Now you try to do something similar when $\;x_0=x_1\;$...but this time you'll find out the function **is** differentiable at $\;x_0\;$ !

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't quite get it, could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @Kalex Read now the added part and try to fill in details.

Comment: Double root...cough, cough.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Thank you and drink some water. What about the double root case?

Comment: @Joanpemo isn't the function differentiable at all points when the quadratic has a double root at the origin?

Comment: @Kalex Yes, it is...and I addreses this at the end of my answer above, and as far as I can see now of the top of my head it doesn't matter where the quadratic has the double root.

Comment: @Joanpemo shouldn't the answer then be $a^2-4b≥0\;$?

Comment: @Kalex No, because $\;\Delta>0\implies\;$ there are two different (real)  roots, and that means the function *isn't* differentiable at these points . When there's a unique root, or when there are no roots at al, i.e. when $\;\Delta\le0\;$, we have differentiability i nthe whole real line.